# Bash command to see which types of operations in c program take most time

Tags: bash, performance, c

This is probably an easy one and I was googling for a long time, but can not find it.

I have written a small C program. It compiles and runs without any problems. But I want to see if there is potential for optimization and where.

Now I want to see which types of operations take the most time. I remember a tool you can use (just putting before the executable on bash) which shows you which types of OS calls take how much time in total.

But I do not find the name of the tool, however I am sure there was one for this purpose.

It is supposed to be executed like this:

```
benchmark_tool my_C_executable argument1 argument2
```

So same as with `time` for example.

Comment: What you are looking for is called "profiling". Search for how to profile your code.

Answer (score 1):

OK, now I found it.

It is:

```
strace -c
```

EDIT: so apparently this is not a "profiling" tool/or is not the right way to do it. The thing is that I had `strace` in mind, this is why I mention it here as an answer. Better solutions are welcome.

Comment: Did I use the term profiling tool? ;) So you think that the output of strace is useless/does not help? It seems to deliver some evidence at least...